# No executables generated by building unit test cpp with catkin

Tags: ros, c++, catkin, gtest, unit-testing

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to build by using `catkin` my `gtest` testsuite.

`catkin_add_gtest` replaces `rosbuild_add_gtest` according to [migrating_from_rosbuild wiki page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/catkin/migrating_from_rosbuild#Differences_in_CMakeLists.txt_for_rosbuild_and_catkin). `rosbuild_add_gtest` generates executable for `gtest` according to [this page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbuild/CMakeLists/Examples#Building_a_C.2BAC8-C.2B-.2B-_unit_test_.28gtest.29). Therefore I expects that `catkin_add_gtest` also generates executable for my test cases. However, no executable is found in my catkin workspace after `catkin_make`ing.

Part of my CMakeLists.txt:

```
include_directories(${mypkg_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES} ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${MYDEPENDLIB_INCLUDE_DIR})
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} ${mypkg_SRCS} ${mypkg_MOCS} ${mypkg_UIS_H})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${QT_QTCORE_LIBRARY} ${QT_QTGUI_LIBRARY} ${MYDEPENDLIB_LIBRARIES})
    
## Setting Unit Test
catkin_add_gtest(testsuite_mypkg test/test_marble.cpp)
target_link_libraries(testsuite_mypkg ${PROJECT_NAME})
```

(A library file specified by `${PROJECT_NAME}` is generated successfully).

Result of `find`:

```
~/catkin_ws$ find . -iname '*test*mypkg*'
./src/mypkg/test/test_mypkg.cpp
./build/mypkg/CMakeFiles/_run_tests_mypkg.dir
./build/mypkg/CMakeFiles/testsuite_mypkg.dir
./build/mypkg/CMakeFiles/_run_tests_mypkg_gtest.dir
./build/mypkg/CMakeFiles/run_tests_mypkg.dir
./build/mypkg/CMakeFiles/_run_tests_mypkg_gtest_testsuite_mypkg.dir
./build/mypkg/CMakeFiles/run_tests_mypkg_gtest.dir
./build/mypkg/CMakeFiles/run_tests_mypkg_gtest_testsuite_mypkg.dir
```

What is missing/wrong?

Also I searched an example that uses the same `catkin_add_gtest` to generate executable, and I found [test_rosbag](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/1bd748ccdb5d19ae266c40f811051df792006c92/test/test_rosbag/CMakeLists.txt). But `catkin_make`ing it hasn't produced any executables either as far as I've tried.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61209/no-executables-generated-by-building-unit-test-cpp-with-catkin/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2013-04-20

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure about intermediate test executables, but there should be tab completable make targets for running the tests. For example:

```
$ make run_tests
```

Should build and run all of the tests.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-04-21**:
I see. I found that my question is basically the same with [this thread](http://answers.ros.org/question/54051/how-do-i-run-unit-tests-for-a-catkin-package/) that you answered.